# Css transition on Table images

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How can i use css transtion for my holiday list, so that when i mouse over on image it need to show big image size and when i mouse out it need to go back to mormal, i know with javascript but i want this to be done with css3 
http://jsfiddle.net/TwRTc/

```
<html>
 <head>
 <style>
# select
{
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition:width 2s; /* Opera */
}
 </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="15" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS; color:#0066CC;">
<tr align="left">
        <TH></TH>
         <th>HOLIDAYS </th>
         <th>DAYS OBSERVED</th>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img class="select" src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/new year1.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1">&nbsp;</td>
        <td> NEW YEARS DAY </td>
        <td>JANUARY 01, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img class="select" src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/bhogi.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>BHOGI/MAKAR SANKRANTHI</td>
        <td> JANUARY 13, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/republic day.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>REPUBLIC DAY </td>
        <td>JANUARY 26, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/ugadhi.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1" ></td>
        <td>UGADI </td>
        <td> MARCH 23, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/good friday.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1" ></td>
        <td>GOOD FRIDAY </td>
        <td>APRIL 06, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/independence day.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>INDEPENDENCE DAY</td>
        <td>AUGUST 15, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/489ramzan.gif" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td> RAMZAN</td>
        <td>AUGUST 20, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/vinaka chowathi.jpg" width="25" height="15" border="1" ></td>
        <td>VINAYAKA CHAVITHI</td>
        <td> SEPTEMBER 19, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/dasara.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>DASARA</td>
        <td>OCTOBER 24, 2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/diwali1.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>DIWALI</td>
        <td>NOVEMBER 13,2012</td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td><img src="C:/Documents and Settings/user/Desktop/images.jpg" width="25" height="25" border="1"></td>
        <td>CHRISTMAS</td>
        <td>DECEMBER 25, 2012</td>
</tr>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the CSS3 scale. I'll write up a quick sample.

This is a simple implementation:

```
img:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    -o-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Bear in mind that you should probably scale down your default image view for the best visual results.

If your images are 300px x 200px, then you'd do it this way:

```
img {
  width: 200px; 
}
```

updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TwRTc/2/